# Display Month and Year in Basic DatePicker

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I am using basic datepicker in my web forms. On one page I just want to display only month and year in basic datepicker. I checked  
[BasicDatePicker Properties](http://www.basicdatepicker.com/documentation/BasicFrame.WebControls.BasicDatePickerProperties.html) but was unable to get any idea.

Updated: 
From the link I got  `BasicDatePicker1.DateFormat = "MMMM yyyy";` 
but the datepicker still shows days.